# $Tr[(\vec{n_{1}}\cdot\vec{\sigma})(\vec{n_{2}}\cdot\vec{\sigma})] = \sum_{k,l}(n_1)_{k}(n_{2})_l2\delta_{kl}$

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, trace

Suppose

$\vec{n_{1}} = \begin{bmatrix}
    n_{1x} & n_{1y} & n_{1z}\\
\end{bmatrix}$

$\vec{n_{2}} = \begin{bmatrix}
    n_{2x} & n_{2y} & n_{2z}\\
\end{bmatrix}$

$\vec{\sigma} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_{x}\\
    \sigma_{y}\\
    \sigma_{z}\end{bmatrix}
$ where each sigma is a Pauli - operator matrix.

How can I convince myself that

$Tr[(\vec{n_{1}}\cdot\vec{\sigma})(\vec{n_{2}}\cdot\vec{\sigma})] = \sum_{k,l}(n_1)_{k}(n_{2})_l2\delta_{kl}$

> The pauli operators are defined below:
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices

Comment: What is  $\vec{a_l}$? You mean $\text{Tr}[(\vec{n}_1\cdot\vec{\sigma})(\vec{n}_2\cdot\vec{\sigma})]$?

Comment: @QuantumSuperfield I have corrected the typo. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt:
\begin{align}
 (\vec{n}_1\cdot\vec{\sigma})(\vec{n}_2\cdot\vec{\sigma})&=(\vec{n}_1\cdot\vec{n}_2)I+i(\vec{n}_1\times\vec{n}_2)\cdot\vec{\sigma}\\
 &=(\vec{n}_1\cdot\vec{n}_2)I+i(\vec{n}_1\times\vec{n}_2)_x\sigma_x+i(\vec{n}_1\times\vec{n}_2)_y\sigma_y+i(\vec{n}_1\times\vec{n}_2)_z\sigma_z
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
 \text{Tr}[(\vec{n}_1\cdot\vec{\sigma})(\vec{n}_2\cdot\vec{\sigma})]&=(\vec{n}_1\cdot\vec{n}_2)\text{Tr}(I)+i(\vec{n}_1\times\vec{n}_2)_x\text{Tr}(\sigma_x)+i(\vec{n}_1\times\vec{n}_2)_y\text{Tr}(\sigma_y)+i(\vec{n}_1\times\vec{n}_2)_z\text{Tr}(\sigma_z)\\&=2(\vec{n}_1\cdot\vec{n}_2). 
\end{align}
Of course,
\begin{align}
2(\vec{n}_1\cdot\vec{n}_2)=2\sum_{k=1}^3(n_1)_k(n_2)_k=\sum_{k=1}^3\sum_{l=1}^3(n_1)_k(n_2)_l2\delta_{kl}. 
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a question on the identity $i(n1 \times n2)\sigma$. How is this arrived at?

Comment: See Eq. (3.2.39) in Sakurai & Napolitano, Modern Quantum Mechanics. The proof is right below this equation.

Comment: Thank you. Which edition is this? Is it the 3rd?
https://icourse.club/uploads/files/65fb4c16648d2b93f82fe3271c3381c211f2f532.pdf
It could be eqn (93.57, 3.58) on page 161

Comment: Eq. (3.57) in the 3rd edition above.

Comment: One last question: what is the significance of the kronecker delta?

Comment: The kronecker delta is not important. The important result is 2(\vec{n}_1\cdot\vec{n}_2). I have rewritten 2(\vec{n}_1\cdot\vec{n}_2) in terms of the kronecker delta because of your question. See my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer is the following one. Since $$\vec{n}_1\cdot\vec{\sigma}=\sum_{k=1}^3(n_1)_k\sigma_k \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \ \vec{n}_2\cdot\vec{\sigma}=\sum_{l=1}^3(n_2)_l\sigma_l$$ we have
\begin{align}\text{Tr}[(\vec{n}_1\cdot\vec{\sigma})(\vec{n}_2\cdot\vec{\sigma})]&=\nonumber\\
 &=\text{Tr}\left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^3(n_1)_k\sigma_k\right)\left(\sum_{l=1}^3(n_2)_l\sigma_l\right)\right]\nonumber\\
 &=\sum_{k=1}^3\sum_{l=1}^3(n_1)_k(n_2)_l\text{Tr}\left[\sigma_k\sigma_l\right]\nonumber\\
 &=\sum_{k=1}^3\sum_{l=1}^3(n_1)_k(n_2)_l(2\delta_{kl})\nonumber\\
 &=2\sum_{k=1}^3(n_1)_k(n_2)_k=2(\vec{n}_1\cdot\vec{n}_2)\nonumber
\end{align}